# Why sort_index removes time portion of datetime columns?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a datetimeIndex:
[image]

but when I try to sort this dataframe using `sort_index()` the time portion of all datetime columns (including the index) is removed. Why? How can I prevent it?
here's the code to sort:

```py
data_date_index.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

and here's my dataframe after running the above line of code:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is weird but when I run `data_date_index.head()` in a different cell, It works just fine (the time part isn't removed)